# How do you create a deconstructor (or similar) in APEX that runs right before an object is destroyed?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

My application has many aggregate fields that need to be updated when any related record is changed, added or deleted. The relationships and calculations are somewhat involved, so I created a class that handles all of the calculations for all of the related tables. There is some SOQL and DML overhead involved in the calculations, so the class handles everything in bulk.

I would like to have the updateAll() method on this class run no more than once per request on all of the records that have been added to its queue. But, there doesn't appear to be "deconstructor-like" functionality in APEX that would automatically get called right before this calculator object was destroyed.

What is the best way to implement this pattern in APEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. I created a Calculator class that recalcs every related aggregate/calculated field in a ~10 table/object relationship. I used triggers on each of those objects to make the calculator class run on the set of related object families to the objects that were changed. I used a static variable on the calculator class to check if the calculator was running in each of the triggers so that they would only call the calculator if it wasn't currently running. It works well enough. A bit inefficient, but stays below governor limits and works in bulk very well. And, I can grow with it...

Comment: Below governor limits of what? Heap size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no way to detect or predict object destruction, since its essentially JSP in the background (shhh, they don't want you to know, it's the "no software" thing ;) ir probably follows its lifetime mechnisms but you can't rely on that.

We actually handle our aggregation in triggers or in te reporting (depending on whether aggregation needs to be stored). Triggers also receive batches as List rather than one-by-one row which allows for batch aggregation and allows us to satisfy the pesky governor. Unfortunately if you have multi-table aggregates you'll need to have triggers for all of them and rerun them for every batch

Comment: There's a loop in the aggregate calculation that makes it a real pain to rely on object triggers. When table A changes, table B aggregates get recalculated, and when table B aggregates change, table A gets recalculated. I can detect the changes or break out of the loop in other ways, but it feels fragile. I'd much rather just use a destructor...GRR

Comment: can you maybe detect the breaking point with one SOQL and thn use aggregate SOQL with where clause constricting the set? And package that into trigger. I am just throwing ideas, I have no idea what your aggregate process looks like.